# Importar dados para o Firebase com arquivo JSON

Tags: json, firebase

estou tendo problemas com a importação de dados para o firebase, eu transformei uma planilha do excel em csv e depois á converti para um arquivo JSON, o cadastro no Firebase é realizado normalmente, porem eu gostaria de saber como gerar as keys com os dados, ao invés de montar uma ordem numérica. Se alguém souber de uma solução agradeço desde já.

### Importe do JSON

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Formato com as Keys

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

As keys são geradas através da função `push()` na DatabaseReference. No android, você pode gerar elas através do código:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String key = mDatabase.child("Productos").push(); // esta é a key
mDatabase.child("Productos").child(key).setValue(/*O producto que você quer salvar*/);
```

Você pode encontrar mais [detalhes na documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write).

Comment: Então, a questão é justamente essa, gerar esses dados através de código é simples. Eu gostaria de saber se existe uma solução quando se esta subindo os JSON manualmente.

Comment: @MatheusRodrigues como é manualmente, talvez o [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?hl=pt-br) seja o ideal. [Mais sobre o assunto.](https://medium.com/@rosariopfernandes/firebase-cloud-functions-f6ed3787fa8d)